# How to remove Views from UITableView custom row on PrepareForReuse?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITable view with a random number of UIImageView in every Single row. In the costruction of the single row, I've used `[self addSubView: xxx]` and a `for` cycle to add every `UIImageView` i need to add (my model has an array of URL). But now I've noticed that when the UITableView reuse the rows and it doesn't clean the `UIImageViews` added.
I've tied to manually remove them in method `onPrepareForReuse` as in the code:

```
 if(_messageContentsFrames != nil){
    for(NVChatMessageContent *singleContent in _messageContentsFrames){
        [singleContent removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

But it gives me error. How can i completely reset the view when it is going to be reused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove these imageViews in -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. That always worked for me.
By the way, do you really need to reuse cells if you make such work with it. Wouldn't it be easier to create new cell?
Or it would be better not to remove imageViews, but reconfigure them on reusing and remove those views, that cell doesn't need.

Comment: Already Tried. It gaves me exception that it couldn't find the instance of selector to remove the view. If i fore the recreation of rows it works. Is it too wrong or i can reuse that?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1.** Set tag to your `UIImageView` (use: `imageView.tag = 123456`) and then in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you should get the specific view using:

```
id imageView = [self.view viewWithTag:yourInteger];
[imageView removeFromSuperview];
```

**Option 2.** Use:

```
for( UIView *view in cell.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperView];
    } 
}
```